# What is the context for these Napoleonic(?) sketches?

Tags: identification, france, art, napoleonic-wars, painting

I'd be interested to know if anyone can put the pictures in this frame into a context.  They were found in the eaves of my late father-in-law's house on Cornwall when the house was being cleared two years ago. He was born in France in WW1 but nothing is known of his father - other than the surname "Barthold". He retained close links with France during his life but this picture is a mystery to the family. If anyone can shed light on any aspect of it (e.g.the era, the regiments, the likely conflict etc) - we'd be very grateful.  [image]

Comment: Anything on the back?

Comment: These do not appear to be of soldiers of the Napoleonic era; probably more like the 1870's or even slightly later.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The images are sealed in the frame and there's nothing on the rear at all. Perhaps I should remove the backing paper and have a look.

Comment: I think this calls for a bit more of analysis in the context of art - what are the dimensions? can the paint medium be identified? What is the support material? (My guess would be gouache on pasteboard.) Are all pictures on one piece of background plate? Are there any marks on the back that may be helpful? One of the questions all this may answer is whether these pictures were planned as one ordered series, or are they just a collection of more-or-less equally themed individual pieces? Could they have been done in an improvised setting, or in a studio?